# Form Validation and fields added with $compile

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a question regarding form validation. It is not working for me in the following scenario:

I have a global form, inside the form dynamic fields are rendered using a directive. That directive based on the type of my field appends a recently compiled directive to the doom.

here is the directive:

```
app.directive('render', function($compile){
    return {
        scope: {model: '='},
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        template:
      '<div class="product-option-selector">'+
      '</div>',
    link: function(scope, element){
      var directive = null;

        switch(scope.model.type){
        case 'number':
          directive =
              '<div data-item-number data-model="model"></div>';
          break;
        case 'text':
          var directive =
              '<div data-item data-model="model"></div>';
          break;
        case 'radio':
          var directive =
              '<div fg-product-option-selector-radio option="option" item="item" index="index"></div>';
          break;
      }
      if(!directive) return;

      directive = '<div>'+directive+'</div>';
      $(element).append($compile(directive)(scope));
    }
    }
});

app.directive('item', function(){
    return {
        scope: {model: '='},
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        template: 
            '<ng-form name="innerForm">'+
            '{{model.name}}'+
             '<input type="text" name="innerVal" ng-model="model.value" required></input>'+
        '</ng-form>'
    }
});

app.directive('itemNumber', function(){
    return {
        scope: {model: '='},
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        template: 
            '<ng-form name="innerForm">'+
            '{{model.name}}'+
             '<input type="number" name="innerVal" ng-model="model.value" required></input>'+
        '</ng-form>'
    }
});
```

I have a button in the form that must be disabled when the form is invalid. The problem is that the button is never disabled.

the html code:

```
<div ng-controller="basicController">
<form name="form">
    <div ng-repeat="f in fields">
        <div data-render data-model="f"></div>
    </div>
    <button ng-disabled="form.$invalid">submit</button>
</form>
</div>
```

my jsFindle link: http://jsfiddle.net/8rz6U/1/

This is a simplification of my problem in the app. the fields directives are more complex, but the code is here.

Thank you,

Comment: seems a lot more complicated tag nesting than needed. You've got all sorts of isolated scopes going on that really aren't required IMO.  Read up on using `mgModel` in docs  http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngModel.NgModelController

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I found solution for this issue, in this Q & A: [AngularJS: Error: No controller: form](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18358744/1679310). The trick is:

1. firstly do append element
2. next do compile

Here is the changed code snippet:

```
directive = '<div>'+directive+'</div>';
// Do Not compile the element NOT beeing part of the DOM
//$(element).append($compile(directive)(scope));

// Firstly include in the DOM, then compile
var result = $(directive).appendTo(element);
$compile(result)(scope);
```

Here is working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wT8Cx/1/)

Comment: You just ended my 1 hour hair-pulling session. Thanks so much!

Comment: And you ended my 3 hour hair-pulling session.

Comment: only 10 minutes of hair-pulling because of this! :)