# How make ui-sref work dynamically via element.append?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to create a pagination directive.
When total_for_pagination is populated, the proper HTML for the pagination is created.

My html: max = max per page

```
<pagination data-number="{{ total_for_pagination }}" data-max="50"></pagination>
```

My directive:

```
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
        scope.$watch(function(){return attrs.number;}, function(){
            //Need to watch because there is a query to db to know how many elements to page.
            var page_element = '<ul>';
            for(var i = 0; i*attrs.max<attrs.number; i+=1){
                page_element += '<li class="pagination"><a ui-sref="users({start: '+i*attrs.max+', end: '+((i*attrs.max)+(attrs.max-1))+'})">'+i+'</a></li>';
            }
            page_element += '</ul>';
            element.append(page_element);
        });
    }
```

What is happening is that when I inspect my html they are as they should be but ui-sref is note changing the state when I click on it. When I just place the same code, works fine.

What I am doing wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What we need here, is to use the angular js core feature: [`$compile`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile). See that in action in [this working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/8MxHZawB7ck6uK43wMEM?p=preview). This is the line with the trick:                 **`$compile(element.contents())(scope);`**

That could be the directive definition:

```
.directive("myDirective", function($compile){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
        scope.$watch(function(){return attrs.number;}, function(){
            var page_element = '<ul>'
            +'<li><a ui-sref="home">ui-sref="home"</a></li>'
            +'<li><a ui-sref="other">ui-sref="other"</a></li>'
            + '</ul>';
            element.append(page_element);
            $compile(element.contents())(scope);  
        });
    }
  }
})
```

which for these states:

```
  .state('home', {
    url: "/home",
    templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
  })
  .state('other', {
    url: "/other",
    templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
  })
```

Will do what we need. Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/8MxHZawB7ck6uK43wMEM?p=preview). See also a bit related: [Form Validation and fields added with $compile](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19882506/1679310)

Answer (score 0):

One way it worked for me is to declare an array in controller/directive and use ng-repeat in html li's. Update the array dynamically and the elements get updated automatically and ui-sref also works. If not, try $scope.apply then.